# VS Code not recognizing string with brackets in SQL code

Tags: sql, json, visual-studio-code, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SQL and trying to extract data from a JSON field that has a "key" name with brackets (`[]`) in it. The brackets do not represent an array, they are simply part of the string/name/identifier. Example contents of the JSON column:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "otherfieldname[1]": 2.5
}
```

The following works effectively in Snowflake SQL to extract the values, but it appears to confuse VS Code:

```
SELECT
    message['status']::int as status 
    , message['otherfieldname[1]']::float as field_1 
FROM
    table_with_message_JSON
```

Here's how VS code looks:
[screenshot of VS Code UI not recognizing the string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOAji.png). It seems to think there is a missing single quote `'`, as it treats everything after the `1]` as text. Is this perhaps a setting that I could change in VS Code? Or is there another way to write the SQL to extract the field value?

To attempt to resolve the issue, I have tried `\` excluding the brackets, and several other methods of getting JSON data, to no avail.

Comment: What language have you set for the file in question for VS Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are writing Snowflake SQL, the regular "SQL" language Visual Studio Code supports doesn't interpret this very well because its not designed for Snowflake SQL.

Install the [Snowflake extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=snowflake.snowflake-vsc).  Your SQL will look much more appropriate afterwards when you select "Snowflake SQL" as your language server:

[image: snowflake SQL example]

You can change your language server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> and select "Snowflake SQL".